# Create all nonexistent nodes and edges if path doesn't exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to represent the modules of a Python package as nodes in a neo4j graph. I get inputs like the following and have to update the graph if the module hasn't already been included. Let's say my inputs look like this:

```
a.b.c.d
a.b.c.e
a
a.b.c
a.b
```

If `a.b.c` already exists, I don't want to recreate those nodes when I encounter `a.b.c.d`. I would only want to make a new node called `d` and connect it to `c`. Likewise if I get `a.b.c` and none of those nodes exist yet, then I want to create all of the nodes and connect them accordingly. My real inputs can have an arbitrary number of nodes per path, so I'd like a Cypher query that can handle arbitrary path lengths.

I'm new to Cypher. Here was my first attempt.

```
MERGE p=(module:Module {name: $module_name})
WITH p, module
MATCH (package:Module)-[:contains*]->(module)
WHERE [x in nodes(p) | x.name] = $module_path
```

However, Cypher gives me the following error:

> Query cannot conclude with MATCH

I also tried this:

```
MERGE p=(:Module)-[:contains*]->(:Module)
WHERE [x in nodes(p) | x.name] = $module_path
```

But then Cypher complains about the presence of `WHERE`.

Note that I'm using the neo4j Python library to run this query, and I pass in parameters like this: `{"module_path":["a","b","c"], "module_name":"c"}`. I'm happy to parameterize my query differently if there is a better way, but I don't think that is the source of my errors.

I'm using neo4j `5.12`, community edition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pure Cypher approach with the following:

```
FOREACH (i IN range(0, size($module_path) - 2) | 
           MERGE (l:Module {name: $module_path[i]})
           MERGE (r:Module {name: $module_path[i+1]})          
           MERGE (l)-[:contains]->(r) );
```

You can test how this works with the data in your question:

```
UNWIND [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','e'],['a'],['a','b','c'],
        ['a','b']] AS modules
FOREACH (i IN range(0, size(modules) - 2) | 
            MERGE (l:Module {name: modules[i]})
            MERGE (r:Module {name: modules[i+1]})          
            MERGE (l)-[:contains]->(r) )
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is achievable with the following query ( added comments )

```
// simulate your input
WITH "a.b.c.d" AS pkg 
// split on the dot, producing an array 
WITH split(pkg, ".") AS parts ['a','b','c','d']
// iterating of the array
UNWIND parts AS part 
// MERGE (match or create) the module with the name as id ( up to you which property to use )
MERGE (m:Module {id: part}) 
// break and introduce a variable being an array of the nodes created or matched
WITH collect(m) AS modules 
// use APOC to link those nodes together with the NEXT relationship
CALL apoc.nodes.link(modules,'NEXT')
```

It produces such graph

[image]

Later on, if you try to do the same with module paths that do already exist, it will do nothing, for eg after the above, the following query will not create anything

```
WITH "a.b.c" AS pkg
WITH split(pkg, ".") AS parts
UNWIND parts AS part
MERGE (m:Module {id: part})
WITH collect(m) AS modules
CALL apoc.nodes.link(modules,'NEXT')
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your command verbatim I get the following error: "There is no procedure with the name `apoc.nodes.link` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed." Which version of neo4j are you running? I'm on 5.12, community edition.

Comment: It assumes you have APOC enabled https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/